# Publicly visible lock object: Sometimes useful or indication for design flaw?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I'm monitoring a subcontracted supply of a software component managing some low level network communications. Reviewing this component i found this:

```
public static object SyncRoot { get { return syncRoot; } }
```

Within this very essential class nearly any method uses this lock object while doing things. Now i wonder if this is good decision to implement such a bottleneck or is it after all a serious design flaw. Isn't this some weird kind of multithreading the procedural way?

Besides the problem of possible deadlocking is locking quick? How high is the monitoring efford to manage all this concurrend threads? 
Wouldn't it be better (if somehow necessary) to implement something like a synchronous Pause/Resume-Method to get this class stop/start working from outside?
In what situation is a publicly visible lock-object usefull? Is there any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Public SyncRoot is used in the MS framework, it is true, but that is an instance property, not a static property.  You don't give any detail about the scope or accessibility of the syncRoot object returned by the (Static) SyncRoot property in your example.  The documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx) warns against locking on a public type, or an object "beyond the control of your application".  There's a very good discussion of multithreading at http://www.albahari.com/threading/.

Comment: Good point. I didn't notice the `static` property. This makes it even more dangerous to publicly expose such a locking construct.

Comment: On the other hand, if the resource being protected is statically available, it would make sense to have a static lock object.  For example, consider several instances of a class, each running on its own thread, locking on a private non-static field before writing to the console.  The locks won't block, and the console output will be jumbled.

Comment: Phoog i think your first thought was right. It smells and the warning within the documentation says it all. Static - okay; public - at least somehow okay but dangerous; public and static - no way. +1for the albahari-link.

Answer (score 1):

The `SyncLock` is essentially a design flaw in the .NET framework. For this reason the .NET 2.0 collections don't expose this property directly (it is implemented explicitly and needed for backward compatibility). The problem is that locking is often to granular, locking is happening at a level that is too low. Usually this problem can be solved by locking at a higher level component, that controls the collection.

Using the `SyncRoot` property there are indeed changes of having deadlocks, because you have no control over how consumers use that locked object. They might also take a lock for a very long time, or forget to unlock it. The idea of Pause/Resume sounds very scary.

The usual thing to do is to make the component thread-safe. When you do this, you won't need the `SyncRoot` property.

Comment: Good point. It seems that the locking was added afterwards to get some cheap kind of thread-safety.

Answer (score 0):

this is often used for collection synchronisation within the MS framework

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection.syncroot.aspx

Comment: This was the pattern that Microsoft recommended with the first few .NET releases, but it's generally discouraged these days. (Obviously implementations of older interfaces like `ICollection` have to maintain that behaviour for backwards-compatibility.)